# Haskell Implicit parameters and polymorphic recursion

Tags: haskell, monomorphism

I have a question on
"[Implicit parameters and polymorphic recursion](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/8.8.4/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#implicit-parameters-and-polymorphic-recursion)" chapter of GHC User Guide.

The code is

```
len1 :: [a] -> Int
len1 xs = let ?acc = 0 in len_acc1 xs

len_acc1 [] = ?acc
len_acc1 (_:xs) = let ?acc = ?acc + (1::Int) in len_acc1 xs

------------

len2 :: [a] -> Int
len2 xs = let ?acc = 0 in len_acc2 xs

len_acc2 :: (?acc :: Int) => [a] -> Int
len_acc2 [] = ?acc
len_acc2 (_:xs) = let ?acc = ?acc + (1::Int) in len_acc2 xs
```

The chapter says

> In the former case, len_acc1 is monomorphic in its own right-hand side,
> so the  implicit parameter ?acc is not passed to the recursive call.
> In the latter case,     because len_acc2 has a type signature,
> the recursive call is made to the    polymorphic version, which takes
> ?acc as an implicit parameter.

The questions are

- Does "monomorphic in its own right-hand side" mean in this case the type
  `len_acc1 :: (?acc :: Int) => [a] -> p`?  Why does ghci say `len_acc1 :: (?acc::Int) => [a] -> Int`?
- Why the first function is monomorphic and the second is not?  If my understanding had been correct, it would be vice versa.
- Or may be it means that the type is `len_acc1 :: [a] -> Int`, but each case refers to `?acc` implicit value, so I believe the type should mention `(?acc :: Int)` constraint.
- How that monomorphism implies that the implicit parameter is not passed to the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Haskell, we often refer to type signatures with type variables as polymorphic, like the polymorphic function `id` whose type signature here includes the type variable `a`:

```
id :: a -> a
```

However, this signature is polymorphic not because it includes the type variable `a` but because that variable is *quantified*.  In Haskell, type signatures are implicitly universally quantified, so the above is equivalent to:

```
id :: forall a. a -> a
```

which is actually accepted syntax if you turn on the `ExplicitForAll` extension.  It's this quantification that makes the type polymorphic.

When Haskell is typing bindings without a type signature, it uses the Hindley-Milner typing algorithm to assign types.  This algorithm works by assigning monomorphic type signatures to sets of mutually-dependent bindings and then refining them by determining the relationships between them.  These signatures are allowed to contain type variables (!), but they are still considered monomorphic because the variables aren't quantified.  That is, the variables are imagined to stand for specific types, we just haven't figured them out yet, because we're in the middle of type-checking.

Once type checking completes, and the "final" monomorphic types have been assigned, there's a separate generalization step.  All the type variables that remain in the monomorphic types, that haven't been determined to be fixed types like `Int` and `Bool`, are generalized by universal quantification.  That step determines the final, polymorphic types of the bindings.  Constraints are part of the quantification process and so are only applied to type signatures at the generalization step when we move from monomorphic to polymorphic types.

The documentation is referring to the fact that, when inferring `len_acc1`'s type, the algorithm assigns it a monomorphic type, ultimately the final monomorphic type `len_acc1 :: [a] -> Int` with a free (i.e., unquantified) type variable `a`.  While the type checker will note that an `(?acc :: Int)` constraint is demanded, it doesn't make this part of the inferred type of `len_acc1`.  In particular, the type assigned to the recursive call of `len_acc1` is the monomorphic type `[a] -> Int` with no constraint.  It's only after this final monomorphic type for `len_acc1` has been determined, is it generalized by quantifying over `a` and adding the constraints, to yield the final top-level signature.

In contrast, when a top-level polymorphic signature is provided:

```
len_acc2 :: forall a. (?acc :: Int) => [a] -> Int
```

the binding `len_acc2` is polymorphic (together with its associated constraint) everywhere it's used, in particular in the recursive call.

The result is that `len_acc1` is recursively called monomorphically, without a constraint dictionary supplying a (new) `?acc` parameter value, while `len_acc2` is called polymorphically, with a constraint dictionary for the new `?acc` value.  This situation is, I believe, unique to implicit parameters.  You wouldn't otherwise encounter a situation where a recursive call could be typed both monomorphically and polymorphically in such a way that the code would behave differently under the two typings.

You'd be more likely to run into a situation like the following, where an "obvious" type signature is required because no monomorphic type can be inferred:

```
data Binary a = Leaf a | Pair (Binary (a,a)) deriving (Show)

-- following type signature is required... 
-- toList :: Binary a -> [a]
toList (Leaf x) = [x]
toList (Pair b) = concatMap (\(x,y) -> [x,y]) (toList b)

main = print $ toList (Pair (Pair (Leaf ((1,2),(3,4)))))
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, I need some more time to understand it.  In particular, I don't understand why that final generalization step of type inference is not done when monomorphically calling `len_acc1` and how it can be called without `(?acc :: Int)` constraint provided there is a reference to the `?acc` in the body of the function.  In your example of polymorphic recursion ghci just complains that it can't infer the type, but in the implicit parameters case it skips a step in type inference.

Comment: Well, in my example of polymorphic recursion, GHC tries to infer a monomorphic type, which leads to a type error.  In the implicit parameter case, GHC tries to infer a monomorphic type, which succeeds because implicit parameters are weird.  So, the same step is "skipped" in both cases, it just unfortunately **fails** to lead to a type error in the second case, giving an unexpected result.

Comment: Ok, but how `len_acc1` can run without any `(?acc :: Int)` when it refers to it?  If I changed return value to `IO Int` and printed `?acc` from the body of that function.  It still returned 0, but I could see that `?acc` actually is given the 0 value, so it looks like some `?acc` is passed, and it looks like that it is from the binding inside `len1` function.

Comment: The polymorphic function `len_acc1` runs with an `(?acc :: Int)`.  If you query its type in GHCi, the constraint is still there.  Think of it as being similar to:   `len3_acc acc xs = go xs where { go [] = acc; go (_:xs) = let acc = acc+1 in go xs }`.  Here `len3_acc` is similar to the polymorphic call, which gets called with the implicit parameter dictionary, and `go` is similar to the monomorphic call, which can use the parameter in its definition but doesn't recursively pass the (rebound) implicit parameter dictionary along.

Comment: It might also help to understand that this behavior isn't really meant to be understood and "used" in real-world code.  It's just an unfortunate consequence of a feature (that was perhaps a little dodgy to begin with) behaving oddly in an unusual case.

Answer (score 0):

I can only answer the question partially.

> Why does ghci say `len_acc1 :: (?acc::Int) => [a] -> Int`?

It's `Int` because the first clause returns `?acc` and it can be inferred to be `Int` from `?acc + (1::Int)` in the second clause.

> "in... right-hand side"

means the part after `=`, which has type `Int` as above, which is monomorphic. `len_acc1 :: (?acc :: Int) => [a] -> p` would be *poly*-morphic.

> Or may be it means that the type is len_acc1 :: [a] -> Int, but each case refers to ?acc implicit value, so I believe the type should mention (?acc :: Int) constraint.

This is what it seems to be saying to me; that at least temporarily it's treated as having that type. But then I don't understand why it compiles at all.

I've tried to read [the paper](http://galois.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/pub_JL_ImplicitParameters.pdf) where implicit parameters were defined, but didn't find the answer.